# Find the length of longest consecutive sub-sequence of a sequence in O(n) time where all elements are less than 10^6

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to find the the length of largest increasing sub-sequence of an array such that difference between any two consecutive elements of sub-sequence is 1
For example: {5,4,2,1,6,2,3,4,5}
length of largest consecutive increasing sub-sequence : 5 {1,2,3,4,5}
SO far I have tried this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a[1000001];
int m[1000001]={0};

int main() 
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
        m[a[i]]=i;
    }
    int maxm=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(m[a[i]-1]==0 || m[a[i]]<=m[a[i]-1])
        {
            int k=a[i];
            int prev = m[k];
            k++;
            int c=1;
            while(m[k]>prev)
            {
                c++;
                prev=m[k];
                k++;
            }
            maxm=max(maxm,c);
        }
    }
    cout<<maxm;
    return 0;
}
```

But this is giving wrong answer for cases like{2,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,3,5}
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: you tagged that C++ because of `cin` ? because it's basically C with all array quirks. You should use `vector`, exact-sized arrays with only your data and the `at` method so you would be sure your indexes are always correct.

Comment: Iám doubtful about my algorithm

Comment: me too, I dont get the whole point of this array `m`. It stores the index of the last occurence of each number in the array `a`. Why?

Comment: I am using m as a map to store last index of a number

Comment: this I got, but why are you doing this?

Comment: to get occurrence of next consecutive element

Comment: Are you sure that this can be done in O(N) ? Link to the original problem would be really appreciated

Comment: lets say you have {1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3} then the biggest subsequence is the first five elements, but your `m` will hold the last three indices for the numbers 1,2,3 and those indices are of no use to find that subsequence, or am i missing something?

Comment: @tobi303 yes I figured out that in the counter test case which I hvae given but I can't find any other way to proceed further

Comment: as I thought, to do this in O(N) you need to mention that all elements of the array are <= 10^6

Comment: I would suggest you to start from the beginning instead of proceeding further ;). That `m` is just the wrong concept to solve the problem.

Comment: @PRP sorry I have edited.

Comment: @tobi303 I will try thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's discuss the algorithm here rather than jumping to the answer/code.

Associate a value with each element. The value with any element `X` will be how many elements from `X-1` till `1` have I seen before I encountered `X` and add 1 to the value because now we have encountered `X` also.

So since an element of an array is strictly between **1 <= A[i] <= 10<sup>6</sup>** we are in luck.

We make an array for each of the elements, whether they appear in the array or not. This kind of approach is similar to [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)
 but since all our elements are integers, **we are using an array as a simple hash table where key is the index of the array and value is the `hash_table[index]` i.e.. the value stores in the index.**

Now lets dry run our approach for one of our sample inputs :

5 1 5 6 2 3 8 7 4

Initiall the hash-table looks like this :

```
hash_table = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; // Not showing indices > 8 because they won't be affected.
```

Now we encounter `5` : 
We look up the value of hash_table[4] and add 1 and put it as the value of `5` i.e. `hash_table[5] = hash_table[4] + 1`

So hash table looks like this  now :

```
hash_table = {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0};
```

Then we encounter `1` : we do the same thing :

```
hash_table = {0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0};
```

Like that after taking in all the numbers hash_table looks like this :

```
hash_table = {0,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1}
```

**Our answer is the maximum value of the hash_table, which is 4.**

**Talk is cheap show me the code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX  (int)1e6
int h[MAX];
int main ()
{
    int N,i,max=0,temp;
    scanf ("%d",&N);
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf ("%d",&temp);
        h[temp] = h[temp - 1] + 1;
        if (h[temp] > max)
            max = h[temp];
    }
    printf ("%d\n",max);
    return 0;
}
```

**So what if you can't upvote. You can still accept this answer if you found it useful !**

Comment: thanks for the answer and your time .Thanks for such detailed answer.

Comment: Pls accept the answer by making the tick on the left side green  if you found it useful.

Comment: Sorry this was my first question here so i wasn't aware about that . Done :)

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking a bit too complicated. You just have to iterate through the array once and count the lenght of sequences and remeber the longest one :

```
int main() {
    int size;
    int input[100000];             
    /* ... get your input with size elements ... */
    int current = 1;
    int biggest = 1;
    for (int i=1;i<size;i++) {
        if (input[i] == input[i-1] + 1) { current++; }
        else { 
            if (current > biggest) { biggest = current; }
            current = 1; 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I don't have enough reputation to upvote :)

Comment: shouldn't input be like `int input[1000000]` instead of 10^5 ?

Comment: @tobi303 this code is giving 3 as output for {2 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 3 5 } whereas it should be 5

Comment: @ananya i think it should be 4 for your example, there was a mistake resulting in `current` being 1 too little, fixed the code